# Refreshing a date subroutine in an HTA application

Tags: html, vbscript, subroutine, hta

Could anyone tell me how I could use document.write to output the date and time from a subroutine, and also have it refresh every minute from when the application is executed? Here is the code I have so far.

```
Sub Window_OnLoad
Daterefresher   
iTimerID = window.setInterval("DateRefresher", 100)
End Sub



Sub ExitProgram
    window.close()
End Sub
Sub DateRefresher()
DateInfo = DateInfo & Now & VbCrLf
DateInfo = DateInfo & Date & VbCrLf
DateInfo = DateInfo & Time & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

After that id like to call it in a div and have it update the time every minute.

I am very sorry ,I am new to VBS, and not an expert with HTML either. Please excuse my poor attempt here.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't use [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) in a subroutine, it would wipe out everything on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Refresh</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
ID="objAutoRefresh"
APPLICATIONNAME="Auto Refresh"
SCROLL="auto"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
>
</head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub Window_OnLoad
    Call Daterefresher()
'1000ms = 1s ==> 1Min = 60*1000 ms = 60000ms
    iTimerID = window.setInterval("DateRefresher",60000) '60000=60s
End Sub
'*******************************************
Sub Daterefresher()
    strHTML = ""
    DateInfo = DateInfo & Date & "<BR>"
    DateInfo = DateInfo & Time & "<BR>"
    DateInfo = DateInfo & Now & "<BR>"
    strHTML = strHTML & DateInfo 
    MyDataInfo.InnerHTML = strHTML
End Sub
'*******************************************
</SCRIPT>
<body><div id = "MyDataInfo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```